# Images not showing for other owners and team members

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have recently had an issue with most of my team members and other owners not being able to see the images on my share point site. It all started when I went into advanced options under permissions, I did not change anything important. Not exactly sure what I did but most of the owners in the same group that I am in cannot see the images presented on our page. I can see all the images that have been uploaded, but everyone else is experiencing issues with seeing them, they are just blank images for them.

Also before I was able to adjust people in specific groups from the permissions in the gear. But I can no longer do that, I have t go to advanced options.

I am new to Share Point so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you remove the Microsoft 355 group permissions from Members group? Other users has permissions on the library/pages where you are saving images?

Comment: So you cannot enter Site permission from thr Gear, but you can still enter Site permission in Site Settings?